# Sort Array inside JSON object gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I want to sort a object in javascript. 
I have this json:

```
var unsorted = {
    "2014": [
        {
            "title": "Book",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "title": "Cheese",
            "value": 2
        }
    ],
    "2015": [
        {
            "title": "Movie",
            "value": 9
        }
    ],
     "2016": [
        {
            "title": "Slay",
            "value": 90
        },
        {
            "title": "Back",
            "value": 22
        }
    ],
    "selected_year": 2015
};
```

So I want to sort the jsons inside these years based on the value. 
I tried it with this:

```
var sorted = unsorted.items.sort(function(a, b) {return a.value - b.value});

alert.log(unsorted);
alert.log(sorted);
```

but the problem is that I have another field which is not json  `"selected_year": 2015` and it throat an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined`

I don't know how to do it? 
Here's my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Byu/146/#&togetherjs=FhkxDaLp6J)

UPDATE: 
I want to sort the arrays inside "years" so I get this:

```
var sorted = {
        "2014": [
            {
              "title": "Cheese",
              "value": 2

            },
            {
              "title": "Book",
              "value": 10
            }
        ],
        "2015": [
            {
                "title": "Movie",
                "value": 9
            }
        ],
         "2016": [
             {
                 "title": "Back",
                 "value": 22
             },
            {
                "title": "Slay",
                "value": 90
            }

        ],
        "selected_year": 2015
    };
```

for example inside "2014" after sorting I have:

```
"2014": [
        {
          "title": "Cheese",
          "value": 2

        },
        {
        "title": "Book",
        "value": 10
        }
    ]
```

Comment: sort is Array's method, `unsorted` is a simple plain vanilla js object.

Comment: Just to be clear about what you're trying to do, objects have no concept of "sorted". But the visual representation can be rearranged, if that's your goal.

Comment: sort() is an array method, your data is a dictionary. You might want to reconsider your data structure or  write your own sorting function

Comment: which one would you like to sort? sort sorts in situ.

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/1018054 ?

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: I just edited the question, I added what I want to do, expected output

Comment: @gurvinder372 I want to sort the Arrays inside it

Comment: @Babel check [**my solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47750447/3669624) below. You were trying to access `undefined` array.

Comment: Strange!! that no one of the upvoted answers pointed to the real problem in your code!!! Actually there's no `unsorted.items`. :o

Answer (score 2):

You can sort only array properties:

```js
var unsorted = {
    "2014": [
        {
            "title": "Book",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "title": "Cheese",
            "value": 2
        }
    ],
    "2015": [
        {
            "title": "Movie",
            "value": 9
        }
    ],
     "2016": [
        {
            "title": "Slay",
            "value": 90
        },
        {
            "title": "Back",
            "value": 22
        }
    ],
    "selected_year": 2015
};

var sorted = Object.assign({}, unsorted);  // Copy the unsorted object

Object.keys(sorted).forEach(key => {
  if (Array.isArray(sorted[key])) {
     sorted[key].sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
  }
})

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: `typeof sorted[key] === 'array'` really?

Answer (score 2):

Only sort those values which are array. You can check for array using `Array.isArray`.

```js
var unsorted = { 2014: [{ title: "Book", value: 10 }, { title: "Cheese", value: 2 }], 2015: [{ title: "Movie", value: 9 }], 2016: [{ title: "Slay", value: 90 }, { title: "Back", value: 22 }], selected_year: 2015 };

Object
  .keys(unsorted)
  .forEach(k => {
    if(Array.isArray(unsorted[k]))
      unsorted[k].sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);
  });

console.log(unsorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the property is an array and sort it as desired.

```js
var object = { 2014: [{ title: "Book", value: 10 }, { title: "Cheese", value: 2 }], 2015: [{ title: "Movie", value: 9 }], 2016: [{ title: "Slay", value: 90 }, { title: "Back", value: 22 }], selected_year: 2015 };

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if (!Array.isArray(object[k])) {
        return;
    }
    object[k].sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    });
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `array of object` and `object` that why you are getting this error, for `selected_yea`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Sort it like this

```js
var unsorted = { 2014: [{ title: "Book", value: 10 }, { title: "Cheese", value: 2 }], 2015: [{ title: "Movie", value: 9 }], 2016: [{ title: "Slay", value: 90 }, { title: "Back", value: 22 }], selected_year: 2015 };
var newArr = [];
for(let i in unsorted){
  if(i !== 'selected_year'){
    unsorted[i] = unsorted[i].sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.value - b.value;
    });
  }
}
console.log(unsorted);
```

***This solution is more faster than others.***

Check Time taken of this : https://jsfiddle.net/q976tk4r/

Other solutions : https://jsfiddle.net/q976tk4r/1/ or https://jsfiddle.net/q976tk4r/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Actually there's no such property `unsorted.items` in your JSON object, there are several keys for years which can be accessed using `Object.keys(unsorted)`.

**Solution:**

So loop over these elements with a `.map()` and check if the element is an `array` with `Array.isArray()` return it sorted, otherwise just return the value:

```
var sorted = Object.keys(unsorted).map(function(k) {
  if (Array.isArray(unsorted[k])) {
    return {
      [k]: unsorted[k].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value
      })
    }
  } else {
    return {
      [k]: unsorted[k]
    };
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var unsorted = {
  "2014": [{
      "title": "Book",
      "value": 10
    },
    {
      "title": "Cheese",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "2015": [{
    "title": "Movie",
    "value": 9
  }],
  "2016": [{
      "title": "Slay",
      "value": 90
    },
    {
      "title": "Back",
      "value": 22
    }
  ],
  "selected_year": 2015
};

var sorted = Object.keys(unsorted).map(function(k) {
  if (Array.isArray(unsorted[k])) {
    return {
      [k]: unsorted[k].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value
      })
    }
  } else {
    return {
      [k]: unsorted[k]
    };
  }
});
console.log(sorted);
```